# String Conversion - remove some characters and replace non-digits with ASCII code

Tags: c#, ascii

I need to take the value CS5999-1 and convert it to 678359991. Basically replace any alpha character with the equivalent ASCII value and strip the dash. I need to get rid of non-numeric characters and make the value unique (some of the data coming in is all numeric and I determined this will make the records unique).

I have played around with regular expressions and can replace the characters with an empty string, but can't figure out how to replace the character with an ASCII value.

Code is still stuck in .NET 2.0 (Corporate America) in case that matters for any ideas.

I have tried several different methods to do this and no I don't expect SO members to write the code for me. I am looking for ideas.

to replace the alpha characters with an empty string I have used:
strResults = Regex.Replace(strResults , @"[A-Za-z\s]",string.Empty);

This loop will replace the character with itself. Basically if I could replace find a way to substitute the replace value with an the ACSII value I would have it, but have tried converting the char value to int and several other different methods I found and all come up with an error.

```
foreach (char c in strMapResults)
  {
   strMapResults = strMapResults.Replace(c,c);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post the code if you tried anything.

Comment: What do you want the result to be if the content contains other ASCII characters, e.g. `"+=/>"`? Do you need these stripped too, or can you guarantee that they won't arrive in the input?

Comment: Simon I know the values will not contain any other ASCII characters as the source system feeding this one does not allow those characters. The source system only allows A-Z and then dash as part of the data field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if each character is in the a-z range. If so, add the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) to the list, and if it is in the 0-9 range, just add the number.

```
public static string AlphaToAscii(string str)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
         if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
            result += (int)c;
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            result += c;
    }
    return result;
}
```

All characters outside of the alpha-numeric range (such as `-`) will be ignored.

If you are running this function on particularly large strings or want better performance you may want to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 2):

For all characters in the ASCII range, the encoded value is the same as the Unicode code point. This is also true of ISO/IEC 8859-1, and UCS-2, but not of other legacy encodings.

And since UCS-2 is the same as UTF-16 for the values in UCS-2 (which includes all ASCII characters, as per the above), and since .NET `char` is a UTF-16 unit, all you need to do is just cast to `int`.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(str.Length * 3); // Pre-allocate to worse-case scenario
foreach(char c in str)
{
   if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     builder.Append(c);
   else if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
     builder.Append((int)c);
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Though a fine answer, I think the discussion of _Unicode; UCS-2; UTF-16_ is perhaps off-topic and a tiny bit confusing when the OP has only mentioned ASCII.  Maybe include it as a footnote? :)

Comment: Actually shouldn't `c >= 0 && c <= 9` be `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` or something?

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo. Don't see how it's off-topic, the bit about Unicode, UCS-2 and UTF-16 is the bit that's an answer. The example code at the end is the bit that could be removed.

Comment: @Micky I think ASCII vs. UCS-2 is important part of the answer as "ASCII code" (when interpreted in strict sense) limits values to 1-127 vs huge variety of "characters" (including surrogate pairs) supported by .Net.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how you might do this with a regular expression (you mentioned regex in your question), here's one way to do it.

The code below filters all non-digit characters, converting letters to their ASCII representation, and dumping anything else, including all non-ASCII alphabetical characters. Note that treating `(int)char` as the equivalent of a character's ASCII value is only valid where the character is genuinely available in the ASCII character set, which is clearly the case for `A-Za-z`.

```
MatchEvaluator filter = match =>
{
    var alpha = match.Groups["asciialpha"].Value;
    return alpha != "" ? ((int) alpha[0]).ToString() : "";
};

var filtered = Regex.Replace("CS5999-1", @"(?<asciialpha>[A-Za-z])|\D", filter);
```

Comment: Nice usage of group name too to document what expression is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "CS5999-1";
            MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(Replace);
            string results = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Za-z\\-]", evaluator); 
        }
        static string Replace(Match match)
        {
            if (match.Value == "-")
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] ascii = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(match.Value);
                return ascii[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: The person who asked question was familiar with Regex but wasn't aware of evaluators.  The answer did not need additional comments with the experience of the poster.